# Tagcloud: different color for different text size

Tags: tags

I'm using `<?php wp_tag_cloud( $args ); ?>` to create a tag in my sidebar.
With the "args" you can style it quite a bit, even the different text size, but it doesn't seem to be possible to apply different colors.

What I did is a plain CSS solution which looks somewhat like this:

```
#tagcloud ul .tag-link-8 {
color:#666;
}

#tagcloud ul .tag-link-7 {
color:#7EA7C9;
}

#tagcloud ul .tag-link-9 {
color:#6A9EA5;
}
```

It works okay, but this is a hassle. I have to apply the colors manually and once I have 50 tags or so this will be kind of ridiculous.

I was wondering if there is a way to connect e.g. the text-size to a specific color (like some tagcloud plugins seem to do anyways) (size:8 = red etc.)?

Anybody any ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: have you searched the plugins? for example http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=tag+cloud+color

Comment: @Michael: Yes, but maybe I should have mentioned that I do not want to use a plugin! :)

Comment: disect the plugins and extract the respective code and add it into functions.php of your theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [filter for the tag cloud](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50261/73) to change the inline size declarations to CSS classes and declare the colors in your style sheet:

```
.tag-cloud-size-8
{
    color:     #009;
    font-size: .8em;
}
.tag-cloud-size-10
{
    color:     #900;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```